# Observable subscribe within component change not working

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I have a subscribe to a firebase object observable inside my component. This subscribe listens for when observable switches from true to false and vice versa. 
Currently this is not working for me, it only spits out false (the initial value even though I know that it is changing correctly in the database.

Service

```
private ReadyObs;

SetRoom(){
    this.Room = this.AngularFire.database.object('/Rooms/ABC1');
    this.Room.subscribe(snap => {
        if(snap.$value !== null){
            this.ReadyObs = this.AngularFire.database.object(`/Rooms/${player.room}/Ready`);
        }
    }
}

checkReady(){
    return this.ReadyObs;
}
```

Component

```
private ReadyObs=this.main.checkReady();

//Always results with still not ready even though its true
this.ReadyObs.subscribe((result) =>{
    if(result === true)
        console.log("Ready to use");
    else
        console.log("Still not ready");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subscribe is taking only the initial value of the subscription which is false. I suggest you look at using Subjects.
[Subject manual link](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject)

I tried a crude example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7mLk3gxn/) if it is what you are looking for.

```
this.ReadyObs=new Rx.BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
this.ReadyObs.subscribe((result) =>{
if(result === true)
  console.log("Ready to use");
 else
   console.log("Still not ready");
 });
```

and

```
this.Room.subscribe(snap => {
    if(snap !== null){
      self.ReadyObs.next(true);
     }
  });
```

Comment: I am not understanding, is it possible to leave an example or elaborate?

Comment: You are checking for ReadyObs and this is supposed to listen to the firebase object right?

Comment: where exactly are you setting ReadyObs ?

Comment: Im setting it within the Room.subscribe method. Is that where I am going wrong? Should  set it outside the subscribe?

Comment: you have a typo.. there it is this.Ready not this.ReadyObs

Comment: That actually is not the typo within my code, sorry I just changed it. It still didn't fix it.